# Core Data with Different View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uikit

I'm still not getting some concepts in Core Data. Bear with me, my app begins with a ViewController that takes some inputs from the user. Once the user clicks on a UIButton, it will transform him to the next ViewController. This is not the case, the problem is that I created an object of the core data inside the UIButton's action outlet:

```
// Creating a new username & Saving it to Core Data
    let newUser = UserInfo(context: self.context)
    newUser.name = usersName.text
    newUser.birthday = bdPicker.date
    newUser.gender = genderTextField.text!
    newUser.prevTested = yesOrNoTextField.text!
    newUser.score = 0
```

I declared the context as a global in the First ViewController:

```
var info:[UserInfo]?
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

Now, in the all the remaining ViewControllers, I need to modify the `newUser.score` entity. Since the app is question-and-answer, I need to modify the score each time I display a question to the user in each view controller. I tried so many solutions, but did not work. I've been told I should create `newUser` as a Property instead of a local variable. How is this possible?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to write: `context.save()` after creating your new user.

Comment: @TheSwiftCoder No, it's there but I did not include it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use the **Singleton Pattern**. Essentially, you create a new class, and create a static variable (by convention, often named `shared`) that's initialized to an instance of the class. Add a newUser property to this class, and then you can view or modify its state across all your ViewControllers.

```
class Singleton{

     var shared = Singleton()

      //Declare your newUser here
}
```

Additionally, if you are using CoreData in your application, I highly reccomend ommiting the use of the global variable for the `context`, and the placement of your CoreData save logic inside of the ViewController class. Instead, write another class, such as `CoreDataManager` or `CoreDataService` (You can call it whatever you'd like) and declare context as a property of that class so that it can be used in your create, fetch, and save operations.

Comment: 1. context.save() when ever you do some change.
2. Get object from db we go to new view controller. Dont pass same object to next controller. 
3. You can use predicate while query db table.

Comment: If I create a dedicated file for core data like `CoreDataManager`, what will be the use of the AppDelegate since it has the Core Data Stack `persistentContainer` and the `saveContext` method? Also, what else might I include inside this `CoreDataManager` besides the context?